# Send UIImage to server

Tags: ios, ios4, uiimage

I want to send UIImage from my application to the server. I use ASIHTTPRequest. I'll send NSData but how to convert from UIImage to NSData?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need PNG data in your NSData you can use:

NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);

Where img is your UIImage. There is a similar function for JPG.

Answer (score 2):

The UIKit functions [`UIImageJPEGRepresentation()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIImageJPEGRepresentation) and [`UIImagePNGRepresentation()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIImagePNGRepresentation) should do what you want.